# Constructing a mobius strip as an identification space

Tags: general-topology

Construct a mobius band explicitly as an identification space of $X=[0,3] \times [0,1]$.

Is this all I have to do for this problem?

Take $X$ to be the set $X=[0,3] \times [0,1]$ and partition $X$ into the following subsets:

$(a)$ Sets consisting of points of the form $(0,y),(3,1-y)$

$(b)$ Sets consisting of a single point $(x,y)$ where $0<x<3,0\leq y \leq 1$.

The resulting identification space is the mobius strip.

Anything else I need to show?

Comment: For $(a)$ do you mean $\{(0,y),(3,1-y)\}$?

Comment: This is the standard way, hea. The only other thing I can think of is if you already have another definition and need to prove this identification space is homeomorphic. Usually this is the definition, though.

Answer (score 0):

The $3$ in your first ordered pair in (a) is presumably a typo for $y$ but otherwise no, there's basically nothing else to show.